# Open Program from C# - also specifying the working directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have some code that launches an external program, although is it possible to specify the working directory, as the external program is a console program:

Code:

```
private void button5_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"update\update.exe");
    }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object to specify all the params you need and then just pass it to the `Start` method like that:

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
...

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"update\update.exe");
  psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\workingDirectory";
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the Working Directory using [ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx).

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
...

var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"explorer.exe");
  processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: @ Thank you, much appreicated