# Open Visual Studio project using c# Process.Start()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-project

In my situation, I have a zip file which contains Visual Studio Project (the csproj file, bin and obj folder,...). This zip is exported from a database and unzipped in custom temporaly directory using .NET C#. The problem appears when I start the csproj file using Process.Start() method. VS loads the project but the project files are not found and are marked with exclamation mark. After I checked, it appeared that the csproj file is loaded from the default Temporaly Internet Files folder. If I open Windows Explorer and go to my custom directory and double_click the file, the project is loaded correctly.
Does anyone know how can I tell Visual Studio to load my project using C# code?

Comment: Is extracting to your own tempdir out of the question?

Comment: Yes. The files are ok after unzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to specify the correct working directory for the **Process.Start()** command.

I believe this question will help you out with this:
[Open Program from C# - also specifying the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239662/open-program-from-c-sharp-also-specifying-the-working-directory)